# Why is the menu icon not triggering when clicked on?

Tags: javascript

I have a very basic mobile nav set up to build on the functionality for future projects. This looks like it should be working to me as it's a very basic toggle of the mobile nav using translateX.

Can anyone see an error somewhere that is preventing this from working?  Once I have this basic functionality I want to build on it.  This is driving me crazy, Thank you for any input.

```
const mobileNav = document.querySelector(".mobile-nav");
const menuIcon = document.querySelector(".bars");

menuIcon.addEventListener("click", toggleMenu);

function toggleMenu() {
  if (mobileNav.classList.contains(".mobile-nav-visible")) {
    mobileNav.classList.remove(".mobile-nav-visible");
    menuIcon.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mobileNav.classList.add(".mobile-nav-visible");
  }
}
```

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific about what isn't working and include the html here as well. Looking at the CodePen, I'm seeing the `mobile-nav-visible` class being added on click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`contains` (*and all `classList` methods*) does not work with css selectors, but with the class name directly. So remove the `.` from the start of the class names.

So use

```
function toggleMenu() {
  if (mobileNav.classList.contains("mobile-nav-visible")) {
    mobileNav.classList.remove("mobile-nav-visible");
    menuIcon.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mobileNav.classList.add("mobile-nav-visible");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - That was it!  Appreciate it.  Removed the . and it works now

Comment: @user55555 you might also want to add a `z-index` to the `.menu-icon` so that it shows above the sliding menu.

Comment: Yes...going to style this up in a few different ways, was just getting the functionality working, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 other ways you can do this

You have to include the "left: 0" property inside your ".mobile-nav-visible" class so it will center the nav. You used "transform:X(100%)" to it so it forces the nav to display outside the screen (100% to the right).

OR

Manipulate the display behavior through the "transform" property. Like this

```
.mobile-nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(285%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(285%);
    transform: translateX(285%); // force the nav to display outside the screen
    height: 100vh;
    width: 50%;
    background: #e6e6e6;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.mobile-nav-visible {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the if conditional where you are removing the class, set the display of your movileNav to none and then set it back to block in the else condition.

It will make your menu appear when clicking on the hamburger icon on phone but you will need to write separate css to close the menu as the button gets overlapped by the menu.